# border and icon when an item is selected in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I have been doing some research for to make this. what  i want is i have a `GridView` items with different background colors and rounded corners. when user click any item it will show a tick icon in center of grid item and a white border. also user can only select one at a time which means if they press another item the tick mark and border needs to be hide on current item.

This is what i tried so far:

MianActivity:

```
//somecode
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        // Constructor
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final MarkableImageView imageView;

            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new MarkableImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
                imageView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            }
            else
            {
                imageView = (MarkableImageView) convertView;
            }
//setting rounded corners on every item
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
            final GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
//setting bacground colour every item based on array
            drawable.setColor(Color.parseColor(mThumbIds[position]));
//tick mark and border
            imageView.setChecked(true);
            return imageView;
        }

        // Keep all Background Colors in array
        public String[] mThumbIds = {"#9e9d25","#9c26b0","#c62828","#01bcd4","#4e342e","#ffeb3b","#9c26b0","#2f7d32","#ffeb3b","#ff5722","#673ab7"
        };

        public class MarkableImageView extends ImageView {
            private boolean checked = true;

            public MarkableImageView(Context context) {
                super(context);
            }

            public MarkableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
            }

            public MarkableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
                super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            }

            public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
                this.checked = checked;
                invalidate();
            }

            public boolean isChecked() {
                return checked;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                super.onDraw(canvas);
                if(checked) {
                    Bitmap check = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                            getResources(), R.drawable.tick);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(check, 50, 50, new Paint());

                }
            }
```

the Problem is it will show a tick mark on every Grid item and no borders too.Am i doing something wrong? and most importantly how can i make user ca select one item per time? if they press other item current tick needs to be hidden. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Anyone? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: May be you can try: 1. add "gridview.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);" before you setAdapter(). 2. Inside getView(), put "imageView.setCheked(true)" inside a if-else like, "if(gridview.isItemChecked(position)){imageView.setChecked(true);}else{imageView.setChecked(false);}. Hope that help!